# Vector and its Dual space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $V^*$ its dual space.

Consider $\varphi,\psi\in V^*$.

Prove that if $\ker(\varphi)=\ker(\psi)$, then $\varphi,\psi$ are linearly dependent.

I might prove it for finite dimensions, but can't see the proof for infinite dimension vector spaces.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\phi{\varphi}$If $\ker \psi = V$, then $\psi = 0$, so we are done, so suppose $\ker \psi \ne V$, let $v \in V$ with $\psi(v) \ne 0$. If $w \in V$, consider 
$$ w' := \psi(v)w - \psi(w)v $$
Then 
$$ \psi(w') = \psi(v)\psi(w) - \psi(w)\psi(v) = 0$$
hence $w' \in \ker \psi = \ker \phi$. This gives 
$$ 0  = \phi(w') = \psi(v)\phi(w) - \psi(w)\phi(v) \iff 
  \phi(w) = \frac{\phi(v)}{\psi(v)}\psi(w) $$
As $w$ was arbitraty
$$ \phi = \frac{\phi(v)}{\psi(v)}\psi $$
and $\phi$ is a multiple of $\psi$.